# select() working for STDIN but not sockets

Tags: c, sockets, select, networking, tcp

I have the following C code for a TCP client:

```c
#define PORT 8888


void connexion(int sock)
{
    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int retval;

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(0, &rfds);
    FD_SET(sock, &rfds);
    char buf[512];

    retval = select(3, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (retval == -1)
        perror("select()");
    else if (retval) {
        read(retval, buf, 512);
        printf("\nbuf: %s", buf);
        memset(buf, 0, 512);
    }
    connexion(sock);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int sock = 0, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    char *hello = "Hello from client";
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
        return -1;
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
        return -1;
    }
    connexion(sock);
}
```

I try to read the standard input without stop reading sockets. Indeed, I need to be able to receive messages while I write one. To do this, I use the select function.  But I only receive messages from my terminal, never from the server.

The server has nevertheless received the sockets from the client... What is wrong with this code ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: in `select(3, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);` 3 must  replaced by `sock+1`

Comment: `read(retval, buf, 512);` retval is probably 0 or 1 here, You want `retval = read(soc, buf, 512);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not use `select` in the right way, replace

> ```
>     retval = select(3, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
> ```

by

```
    retval = select(sock+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

> select() working for STDIN ...

that works for *stdin* because *stdin* is 1 so is less than 3

Out of that in

> ```
> read(retval, buf, 512);
> ```

does not do what you expect, do

```
if (FD_ISSET(sock, &rfds)) {
  read(sock, buf, 512);
  printf("buf from socket: %s\n", buf);
}
if (FD_ISSET(stdin, &rfds)) {
  read(stdin, buf, 512);
  printf("buf from stdin: %s\n", buf);
}
```

warning if you read on the socket and the null character is not sent/read because `printf` will have an undefined behavior, may be save the read length to add the null character at the end

if the socket is closed or you reach the EOF on `stdin` both `read` may read nothing, so it is better to check their result

Do not use an `else` between the two `if` because you can have input from both

Your terminal recursion can be replaced by a loop

In your `printf` it is strange to produce the newline before and not after, doing after flushes the output

In *main*

> ```
> char *hello = "Hello from client";
> char buffer[1024] = {0};
> ```

are unused

Comment: Thank you, but when I put:

```c
read(sock, buf, 512);
```

I can only read messages from the socket. Now, I can't get the prompt. How can I receive messages from sockets and get the content of my prompt ? I've tried ISSET but not working...